# Generalized Josephus problem

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, induction, recursive-algorithms

I have been reading generalized Josephus problem from [Concrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025). The recurrence form for the problem is given as

```
f(1) = a
f(2n) = 2f(n) + b, for n >= 1
f(2n+1) = 2f(n) + y, for n >= 1
```

The closed form is given as

```
f(n) = A(n)a + B(n)b + C(n)y
where,
A(n) = 2^m                       
B(n) = 2^m-1-l                   
C(n) = l
```

The book then says

```
Next, let’s use recurrence and solution in reverse, by starting with a 
simple function f(n) and seeing if there are any constants (a, b, y)
that will define it. Plugging in the constant function f(n) = 1 says that

1 = a
1 = 2.1+b;
1 = 2.1+y;

hence the values (a, b, y) = (1, -1, -1) satisfying these equations will 
yield

A(n) - B(n) - C(n) = f(n) = 1. Similarly, we can plug in f(n) = n:

1 = a;
2n = 2.n+ b;
2n+l = 2.n+y;
```

I am unable to understand how f(2n) has been replaced with 1 when we assumed f(n) = 1, and how it has been replaced with 2n and 2n+1 when we assumed
f(n) = n. I know its something silly that I am missing but I am unable to see it. Can someone please explain.

Comment: Presumably you mean $B(n)=2^{m-1}-1$.  (and it should be $n$, not $m$).  What you have written simplifies to $B(n)=2^m-2$.  Please use parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have confused yourself by using different variable names $n$ and $m$ on different sides of the equations. The variable $n$ here doesn't have a specific value; it stands for the general argument of the function $n$. Thus, if the *ansatz* $f(n)=1$ is made, you can replace all values of $f$ by $1$, not just ones that literally use 'n' as an argument. Likewise, if $f(n)=n$ for general $n$, then $f(2n)=2n$ and $f(2n+1)=2n+1$.

Comment: How the author got the following equation after the above step?   A(n) = 2^m .